# Web scraping requiring a mouse click?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying (in R) to scrape some data from:

http://www.soccerbase.com/matches/results.sd?date=2012-11-04

namely, I want to get the match details which appear on the page when you press the *i* button. However, the information that appears having clicked on the button is not contained in the original html code. All I can see is a line (where I expected the data to be contained)...

```
<span class="infoField"><a href="#" class="info finished" title="Show full match details"></a></span>
```

...which pretty much leaves me at a dead end...any ideas?

Comment: you should start using firebug in Firefox or chrome dev tools. website makes javascript request to http://www.soccerbase.com/matches/additional_information.sd?id_game=652536

Comment: you should also read the terms and conditions.

Comment: @Spacedman In the USA, at least, those terms and conditions are not legally binding.  See e.g. http://www.forbes.com/sites/ericgoldman/2012/10/10/how-zappos-user-agreement-failed-in-court-and-left-zappos-legally-naked/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)
dataurl<-'http://www.soccerbase.com/matches/results.sd?date=2012-11-04'
sdata<-htmlParse(dataurl)
sid<-xpathSApply(sdata,'//*/tr/@id')
sid<-gsub('^tgc','',sid)
mUrl<-paste0('http://www.soccerbase.com/matches/additional_information.sd?id_game=',sid)
```

The above code would get the required urls for the additional data. However I would check with the site with regards to harvesting their data.